# How to assign unique field name for "Extract Multi Values To Point" operation using arcpy in loop?

Tags: arcpy

I have 1000 of raster file for which I am trying to extract multi values to point in a loop so that I have a series of values for each coordinate.

Here I have one raster for each week, and I want to name the field accordingly in the point shapefile's attribute table while extracting the values.

How to supply the variable name in the command line shown below

```
arcpy.gp.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints_sa(path/to/pointshapefile,"raster_2012_1.tif 2012_1","NONE")
```

Above code line works fine when "raster_2012_1.tif" is open in window and "a specific name "2012_1" is to be assigned. However, in case of varying raster files in loop and varying field name variables are required to be assigned.

I tried to assign variables as follows,

```
arcpy.gp.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints_sa(path/to/pointshapefile, path/to/raster.tif field_name,"NONE")
```

Here I am updating field name in each loop, but it shows following error

```
Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 5)
```

where (line 5) is the shown code line.

I guess this problem must be occurring because of the number of arguments in the command. How to overcome this problem?

**Edit:** Sample code

```
import arcpy
shapefile = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DSBShape\Point.shp'
tif = 'Raster.tif'
header = 'Header'
arcpy.gp.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints_sa(shapefile, tif header, "NONE")
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet (rather than just a line or two) that results in that error on line 5, and the full error message, please?

Comment: I have edited the code, please see.

Comment: Try putting an r in front of your path.

Comment: Thanks but for shapefile it is not giving any error. I mean without putting r in the shapefile path it is working absolutely fine but for raster and field name it is creating problem. Please have a look into the complete script here https://www.dropbox.com/s/vs8aba52x8bpj95/Script.py?dl=0

Comment: I never visit links to get data or code. If it is not in your question then I'm not a potential answerer.

Comment: What are you trying to do with tif header in the last line? Is it not supposed to be a list, like this: [tif, header]

Comment: @BERA I could solve this eventually and added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this question,

Since `ExtractMultiValuesToPoints_sa` only takes two argument, I tried to supply the second argument after adding two strings i.e., first the name of raster file and 2nd name of variable header with a blank save in between and it worked.

```
import arcpy
shapefile = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\DSBShape\Point.shp'
tif = 'Raster.tif'
header = 'Header'
arcpy.gp.ExtractMultiValuesToPoints_sa(shapefile, tif + ' ' + header, "NONE")
```